# stay a few second on interface and switch automatically to an other interface

Tags: android

I have an interface a.xml and a java file a.java and b.java and 2 activity.

I want the interface b.xml (contains only an image)

When opening the application I want the interface b.xml opens and stays 3 seconds and then automatically switch to the interface a.xml

How can I do it?

Thank you in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use these code:

```
Handler handler = new Handler();
handler.postDelayed(new Runnable() {
    public void run() {
        Intent intent = new Intent(ActivityA.this, ActivityB.class);
        startActivity(intent);
    }
}, 3000);
```

Additional links:

- [Handler](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/Handler.html)
- [Update UI from Timer](http://developer.android.com/resources/articles/timed-ui-updates.html)